# How to make a REST API Request with Ajax and session token?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, api

I'm having trouble following an API Guide using AJAX. I have successfully got the session token from the login api as the session token is needed to make requests to GET/POST data.

Code to get the session token:

```js
             
        var sessionToken = null;

        $.ajax({
          url: '<API-URL>/1/json/user_login/',
          data: {
           'login_name' : 'USERNAME',
            'password' : 'PASSWORD'
          },
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) { 
            sessionToken = data.response.properties.session_token;
            $("#result").text("Got the token: " + sessionToken);
          },
          error: function(err) { console.log(err); },
          beforeSend: setHeader
        });
        
      function setHeader(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      }
```

On successful, we get the session token: D67ABD0454EB49508EAB343EE11191CB4389255465

```js
{response: {…}}
response:
properties:
action_name: "user_login"
data: [{…}]
action_value: "0"
description: ""
session_token: "D67ABD0454EB49508EAB343EE11191CB4389255465"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

Now that I have a valid session token, I can now make requests to get data. I'm trying to get driver data using the following code:

```js
            $.ajax({
            url: '<API-URL>/1/json/api_get_data/',
            data: {
              'license_nmbr' : vrn,
              'session_token' : sessionToken
            },
            type: 'POST',
            //dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
              //var obj = JSON.parse(data);
              console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(err) { console.log(err); },
            beforeSend: setHeader
        });
```

According to the documentation, I need to use POST instead of GET in order to get vehicle details in the response and pass the session token as a parameter:

[image: Documentation]

Unfortunately it seems to return blank data when using GET and Permission denied when using POST. I've tried sending the parameters as an array like the documentation but that fails also. I've tried passing the session token as Authorisation but still get no response.

The only help I got from the API support team was: "POST can’t be with parameter query on the end point."

What am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think you just passing in `$.ajax({ data: {} })` just two parameters, but you need fill that with all variables provided in the request example image.

Comment: I'll give that a go and see what happens, cheers

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what service/api you're trying to call, but from the error message you've posted and the brief documentation it looks like you're structuring your url wrong:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '<API-URL>/1/json/api_get_data/',
            data: {
              'license_nmbr' : vrn,
              'session_token' : sessionToken
            },
            type: 'POST',
            //dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
              //var obj = JSON.parse(data);
              console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(err) { console.log(err); },
            beforeSend: setHeader
        });
```

You're including the `action` parameter as part of the url by the looks of things when the doc you posted implies it should be part of the data (and the error they sent you of "POST can’t be with parameter query on the end point." also supports this). So try the following: (of course without seeing more of the docs it's difficult to know if your actual base url is correct)

```
$.ajax({
            url: '<API-URL>/1/json/',
            data: {
              'action': {'name':'api_get_data',
              'parameters': [ {'license_nmbr' : vrn }],

              'session_token' : sessionToken
              }
            },
            type: 'POST',
            //dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
              //var obj = JSON.parse(data);
              console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(err) { console.log(err); },
            beforeSend: setHeader
        });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting a 404. I could send you the jsfiddle if you'd like? I don't really want to post it on here as there's credentials on it.

Comment: If you're getting a 404 then it sounds like the url is wrong now though. From the docs it should give you the base url that you need to call. You could just try removing the trailing '/' from it, though this shouldn't actually matter. Can you share a link to the docs in question at least?

Comment: https://traffilog.gitbooks.io/api/fleet-management/vehicles/get-data/version-1.html